# How to generate random functions using a for loop?

Tags: r

I want to create a random set of functions using a for loop, but my functions end up being the same.

I guess this is related to the environment, but I could not fix it:

```
a <- runif(100)

for(i in 1:100){
  assign(paste0("r",i), function(x){a[i]*x})
  }
```

All the one hundred (r1 until r100) functions created end up being the same.

I would like them to have random **a** parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R anonymous function: capture variables by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216909/r-anonymous-function-capture-variables-by-value)

Comment: ^ it seems that the problem above is the same as yours. However the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216909/r-anonymous-function-capture-variables-by-value#comment66695355_16217307 suggets that the behavior changed in new version.

Comment: You should not create one hundred related objects in the global environment. Forget assign and put them in a list instead.

Comment: What is the benefit of storing all the results in a list? I might be able to feed the same input to all functions at once then ? Thanks for the tip @Roland

Comment: @Rodrigo One advantage is that you can easily loop over all functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an adapted version from the link in user202729's comment:

```
a <- runif(100)

invisible(lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  assign(paste0("r",i), function(x){a[i]*x}, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }))
```

You might have noticed that the functions `r1` to `r100` always evaluated using `a[100]`. This was because `i=100` at the end of the loop. If you changed `i` to something else, you'd get different function evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
for(i in 1:100){
  a <- runif(1)
  assign(paste0("r",i), function(x){a*x})
}
```